# How to extends from data class in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, dto

I want to create data class extend from another data class. I can not extend from another data class because of another data class is data class and i have no chance that change another data class. Another data class must be data class (not interface, open class etc.).

I searched on internet and everyone says you should remove data tag and write open class.
So how to extends from data class ?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot extend a `data class` with another. However, you can create an object of that class like below:

```
data class Student(
    val rollNo: Int,
    val person: Person
)
```

Parent `data class`

```
data class Person(
    val fullName: String
)
```

Usage

```
val student = Student(15, Person("Developer"))
Log.d("MyTag", student.person.fullName)
Log.d("MyTag", student.rollNo)
```

Comment: This is classical composition. So Kotlin favors composition over inheritance?